# Find point on sphere closest to a ray vector

Tags: geometry, vectors

I have a unit vector **v**. It's starting point is **x**. **v** can be assumed to be infinite ray that starts at **x**. There is a sphere at position **y** with radius **r**. I need to find a point on the surface of the sphere that is the closest to the ray, as well as detect if ray intersects the sphere. This needs to be done as efficiently as possible, with very minimal and easy to compute calculations. Note that I'm already checking for a case if the **v** is facing away from the sphere(case when dot product of **v** and (**x**-**y**) isn't positive), so that shouldn't be concerned. This calculation is only needed for case where the previously mentioned dot product is positive. If you know a good way to do this calculation, please, share it!

Comment: the point + vector forms a line.  construct a line through the center of the sphere that intersects your vector at a right angle.  This will penetrate the sphere at the closest point.

Comment: Thanks for the hint! I think I can figure out the math behind this idea by myself now, and if I do, I'll post it down just for everyone to enjoy :)